Change formatted citation call-out produced by 'alpha' bibliography style
I am writing a thesis and I am using BibTex and want to cite a post from math stack exchange. It is the first answer from this post by John Dawkins. Luckily there is a cite function which exactly provides the BibTex reference and I can just copy it into my BibFile. It is just
@MISC{JD17,
    title = {Lebesgue integral of Gaussian process is Gaussian.},
    author = {John Dawkins (https://math.stackexchange.com/users/189130/john-dawkins)},
    howpublished = {Mathematics Stack Exchange},
    note = {URL:https://math.stackexchange.com/q/2398465 (version: 2017-08-18)},
    eprint = {https://math.stackexchange.com/q/2398465},
    url = {https://math.stackexchange.com/q/2398465}
}

My problem: When I create the bibliography using these two commands in my Tex file,
\bibliographystyle{alpha} 
\bibliography{literature.bib}

I get as a reference symbol, i.e. when I cite this in my text, the letters [hd]. For example: As we can see from \cite{JD17}... yields

As we can see from [hd]...

However, instead of [hd] I want it to show [JD17].
Question: Is there a way to change this from [hd] to [JD17]. I would not mind to simply change this manually from [hd] to [JD17], since this is the only reference I use for which this issue occurs.
Any reference or help would be greatly appreciated!
Thanks in advance!
EDIT Here is my Tex Code:
\documentclass[a4paper,11pt,bibliography=totoc,listof=totoc,
    headinclude=true,cleardoublepage=empty,oneside]{scrbook}
\usepackage[english,ngerman]{babel}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{color, soul}
\usepackage{amsmath,amsthm,amssymb,amsfonts}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{psfrag}
\usepackage[font=small,skip=-20pt]{caption}

\usepackage[unicode,colorlinks=false,pagebackref=false]{hyperref}


\KOMAoptions{footinclude=false}
\KOMAoptions{headsepline=false}
\KOMAoptions{DIV=12}
\KOMAoptions{BCOR=8mm}
\pagestyle{headings}

\recalctypearea

\definecolor{change}{rgb}{0,.55,.55}

\def\revision#1{{\color{red}#1}}

\usepackage{mathrsfs}
\usepackage{enumitem}
\usepackage{xfrac}

\begin{document}

Here is my thesis. I cite the math stack exchange post here: \cite{JD17}

\bibliographystyle{alpha}
\bibliography{literature.bib}

\end{document}

The BibFile looks like this (i.e. the file literature.bib)
@MISC{JD17,
    title = {Lebesgue integral of Gaussian process is Gaussian.},
    author = {John Dawkins (https://math.stackexchange.com/users/189130/john-dawkins)},
    howpublished = {Mathematics Stack Exchange},
    note = {URL:https://math.stackexchange.com/q/2398465 (version: 2017-08-18)},
    eprint = {https://math.stackexchange.com/q/2398465},
    url = {https://math.stackexchange.com/q/2398465}
}

The Output looks like this:
Here is my thesis. I cite the math stack exchange post here: [hd]
However I want:
Here is my thesis. I cite the math stack exchange post here: [JD17]

Welcome to TeX.SE! please show us a short complete TeX code resulting in your issue. Then we do not have to guess what you are doing ...

Thanks! I included my TeX code.

Try changing author = {John Dawkins (https://math.stackexchange.com/users/189130/john-dawkins)}, to author = {Dawkins, John}.

@Mico it also needs a year field to print the 17. However, this loses the url part of the author, which in the case of Stack Exchange users may be rather important as identifier (as usernames are not unique and also often not very identifying). So having that information somewhere, printed close to the actual author name, would be nice.

If you add the field year = 2017 to the bib entry, the alpha bibliography style is programmed to generate a citation call-out of the form Daw17. Why create an utterly non-standard form of "alphabetic" citation call-outs?

@Marijn - I agree that providing the additional field year = 2017 is important. (See also the additional comment I've posted in the meantime...) I wouldn't agree, though, with the notion that it's useful -- let alone important -- to provide a URL to the author's page on StackExchange. I'd much rather just provide the URL to the posting in question.

Thanks for the Input. I added the year and removed the user link from the author. This creates [Daw17] which works for me. As a workaround I additionally added the user link in the title brackets, i.e. title = {(Link to user). Lebesgue integral...}. Then the user link is close to the name. Unless there is a better way?

You asked

Is there a way to change this from [hd] to [JD17]?

Not really, at least not with BibTeX and the venerable alpha bibliography style.
Once you fix a number of (mainly minor) glitches in the bib entry in question and backfill the missing year field, the alpha bibliography style will generate a citation call-out of the form [Daw17]. Since this is an entirely standard form that's been around, more of less unchanged, for more than 40 years, I wouldn't recommend you modify it.
The following sample code uses the scrartcl rather than the scrbook document class mainly to simplify the answer's layout.


\documentclass[a4paper,11pt,bibliography=totoc,
               listof=totoc,headinclude=true,
               cleardoublepage=empty,oneside]{scrartcl}

\begin{filecontents}[overwrite]{literature.bib}
@MISC{JD17,
    title   = {Lebesgue integral of {Gaussian} process is {Gaussian}.},
    author  = {John Dawkins},
    howpublished = {Mathematics Stack Exchange},
    note    = {URL: \url{https://math.stackexchange.com/q/2398465} 
               (version: 2017-08-18)},
    eprint  = {https://math.stackexchange.com/q/2398465},
    url     = {https://math.stackexchange.com/q/2398465},
    year    = 2017,
}
\end{filecontents}

\usepackage[english,ngerman]{babel}
%\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc} % that's the default nowadays
\usepackage{color, soul}
\usepackage{amsmath,amsthm,amssymb} % amsfonts % amsfonts is loaded automatically by amssymb
\usepackage{mathrsfs}
\usepackage{enumitem}
\usepackage{xfrac}


\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{psfrag}
\usepackage[font=small%, skip=-20pt % really?
           ]{caption}

\usepackage{xurl} % <-- new
\usepackage[colorlinks,allcolors=blue,pagebackref=false]{hyperref}

\KOMAoptions{footinclude=false}
\KOMAoptions{headsepline=false}
\KOMAoptions{DIV=12}
\KOMAoptions{BCOR=8mm}
\pagestyle{headings}
\recalctypearea
\definecolor{change}{rgb}{0,.55,.55}
\def\revision#1{{\color{red}#1}}

\begin{document}

Here is my thesis. I cite the math stack exchange 
post here: \cite{JD17}

\bibliographystyle{alpha}
\bibliography{literature}

\end{document} 


Thanks! I accept your answer and will just add the User Link to the front of the title as mentioned above.
